# How to get code coverage for specific property #C

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, code-coverage

How do I get code coverage for specific properties?  On an existing model I'm adding a property called `AppTenantsCpgDisplay`.

I need to cover that on my PR.

Not sure if it's possible do something like this?

I want to give it a GUID Value.  Moc Guid value.

```
static private readonly IEnumerable<Guid> Display;
```

Model I'm calling on the test :

```
namespace Offers.Core.Models.Marketing
{
    public class AdvertOfferReadModel
    {
        public ReadModel();

        [JsonProperty("Display", Required = Required.Always)]
        public IEnumerable<Guid> Display { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for how to test code coverage locally?

Comment: @TreyMack I'm getting report from Sonar Cloud

Comment: That test should cover you then. One thing I ran into recently is that [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage] applied at the Assembly level confused Sonar Cloud, so look out for that. If that's not the case, check that the Test Assembly coverage results are being included in the package sent to Sonar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to test the behavior of an auto-generated property. You're not responsible for that correct behavior. The compiler is.

Properties with custom getter/setters are potential candidates for testing though as their correctness depends on your code rather than the compiler.